# Makefile : Shell command issue

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a make file that is related to a open source project in the github but i getting error during on run it

It is first line of this make file and it cause an error

```
NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname `which ndk-build`)
```

and the error is :

```
-bash: shell: command not found
```

what is the mean of shell ?
shell command not found in **Linux**!!

Comment: How are you trying to run the make file? i.e. what is the exact command-line you are executing?
A makefile (e.g. _MyMakefile_) is supposed to be run by passing it to command _make_, e.g.:
`make -f MyMakefile`

Comment: i am executing it with ./MakeFile

Comment: OK, that's the problem! Try to run it by simply running `make`.

Answer (score 0):

The `shell` function does command expansion in the make file. You can refer the [shell function manual in makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) for more information.

For your case `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname 'which ndk-build')` in the makefile, the NDK_PATH should store the directory name where `ndk-build` command locates.

You are not allowed to execute `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname 'which ndk-build')` in your terminal, which will result in the error you post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and solved it like as followings,

you can try this instead

```
NDK_BIN := $(shell which ndk-build)
NDK_PATH := $(shell dirname $(NDK_BIN))
```